# How to use generic type methods in C# when the generic type is absract, TSymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, generics, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to call this method:

```
public string Decrypt5<TSymmetricAlgorithm>(string input) where TSymmetricAlgorithm : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
    {
        var pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_seed);
        using (TSymmetricAlgorithm sa = new TSymmetricAlgorithm())
        {
            ICryptoTransform saDec = sa.CreateDecryptor(pwdBytes, pwdBytes);

            var encBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

            var resultBytes = saDec.TransformFinalBlock(encBytes, 0, encBytes.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes));
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
        }
    }
```

By calling `Decrypt5<TSymmetricAlgorithm>("myEncryptedStringBlahblahxyz");`
But I keep getting an error that I must use a non-abstract type with a public parameter-less type instead of TSymmetricAlgorithm. Is there a default TSymmetricAlgorithm subclass that I can use. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What type are you passing?

Comment: How are you calling `Decrypt5`? Is it in a generic method (your snippet of how you call it looks like it is)? If so putting the same constraints on that method should do the trick...

Comment: @Archer sorry if i wasn't clear. SymmetricAlgorithm is an abstract class in. I tried passing RijndaelManaged like `Decrypt5<RijndaelManaged>("myEncryptedStringBlahblahxyz");` and it worked. This was done through trial and error because it was hard to find C# classes that subclass SysmmetricAlgorithm smh. Thanks for the quick response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `RijndaelManaged` object type did the trick. I found this out through trial and error. If anyone knows a fast way to find out all the native classes in C# that subclass a certain parent abstract class (SymmetricAlgorithm in this case), please feel free to let me know in comments for future reference. I'm new to C# :-)